# Sublime Text 2 - adding Databases - Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, sublimetext2

Looking at moving to the Text editor.  I have all the packages installed and everything is looking great. but  there is still on thing I would love the editor to do.

Using Homesite (yes still work horse) you have the option to view your databases that have been registered in your RDS settings.

Is there a plugin or option to add this type of functionally to sublime text - I constantly need to be able to see the Database structures and tables and column names. Wondering the best way to make this happen.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the RDBM management tool for the particular DB you are using.

Comment: I second @ScottStroz's comment

Comment: RDS is a pretty closed spec so the only tools that use RDS to communicate with the server tend to come from Adobe.  I suppose you could write a Sublime plugin that used the CF Admin API to return your datasources and the `cfdbinfo` tag to introspect those databases but it sounds like a lot of work when you can just do what @ScottStroz and @AdamCameron have suggested and use the proper tool for the job.  Most people move to an editor like Sublime to get away from all the bulky crap that IDEs tend to be overloaded with.

Comment: working on using the RDBM had no clue that there was a plugin for it.